# History back() button not behaving the same as the back button

Tags: javascript, back, html5-history, dom-events, popstate

I expect the pop state event to be called every time the user clicks the back button or history.back() is called. From what I've read, history.back() is equivalent to using the back button on the browser.

I have a situation where, I push a state onto the history stack when opening an overlay, and call history.back() when the user clicks the close button to close the overlay. This is equivalent to clicking the back button.

The browser back button always works correctly - i.e. it fires the popstate event, and executes my custom popstatehandler correctly. However, the history.back() function does not always call the popstate event (and hence does not close the overlay).

This suggests that there is some inherent difference between the two, but I don't know what that is!

This mysterious buggy behavior only occurs when I open the page in question  by clicking a link to open the page in a new tab. Opening the page directly makes the popstate event fire just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other action (like an error that is thrown)  taking place that prevent the code that closes the overlay to be executed. How do you verify that the `popstate` callback is/was not called?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

a) Yes, absolutely sure since I put logs all over the javascript and code 
after the history.back() call executes just fine.

b) I have a popstate event handler, where I print to console. It's fired when you click the browser back buton, but does not work when I call history.back().

Comment: I have experienced this exact same thing when working with modals, and trying to have the back button, and a close button on the modal close the modal. Using `history.back()` seems to refresh the page, while the browser back button does not.